# How to colorize all @replies in a Twitter conversation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to make a greasemonkey userscript that will work in Twitter conversations
(colorize names,usernames and each 1st `@reply`).

As a start, I want all text and @replies in the tweets to have the same color (black).
**The problem that I have is that, usually `@replies` in twitter conversations are not black (as the rest of the tweet text -except URLs which I don't mind-) but has some other color.**
For example [here](https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/501392234299002880) they are gray.

**I want to turn them all into black.**

Using Firefox's Inspector, I've noticed in the page source code that:

- the `@` and `reply` are seperate (the 1st is inside a `<s>` tag while the 2nd in a `<b>` tag).
- they all belong to the same class. I think it's `twitter-atreply pretty-link`.

So, I've tried this code:

```
var replies = document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-atreply pretty-link');
for (i = 0; i < replies.length; i++) {
  replies[0].style.color = 'black';
}
```

But, it doesn't work (it doesn't generate any error, neither).
**How can I make it work?**

Comment: are you positive that 'twitter-atreply pretty-link' is the correct selector? I just tried this snippet for a link on this page and it worked.

Comment: I can't say for sure, but (using the Inspector) if I hover the mouse on such HTML line containing `class="twitter-atreply pretty-link`, the relevant `@reply` is highlighted.

Comment: The `@` and the `reply` in HTML the HTML code are as follows: 
the 1st inside a `<s>` and the 2nd inside a `<b>` ([http://i.imgur.com/4Ei0WNc.png](http://i.imgur.com/4Ei0WNc.png)). Executing my script, it appends `style="color: black;"` in the initial line (http://i.imgur.com/PLRfUKO.png). If it was appended inside the `<s>` and `<b>` instead (i.e http://i.imgur.com/wlV7HGc.png) then it should work (I tried it by manually appending it in the HTML code). But how?

Comment: you'll need to add some more javascript to iterate on the children. I'll add it as an answer

Comment: also, the issue might be that you're changing the style of replies[0], not replies[i] each time. otherwise the code below should work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're changing the style of the div that *contains* the elements you're trying to style, rather than the elements *themselves*.

Currently this page uses an 'a.twitter-atreply.pretty-link' with  and  elements as children containing the text you want to style. So all you need to do is loop over these children, and it should work.

```
var replies = document.getElementsByClassName('twitter-atreply pretty-link');
for (i = 0; i < replies.length; i++) {

  var children = replies[i].children;

  for (j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
    children[j].style.color = 'black';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying to help. I tried your code in the conversation link I gave in my question but it shows `Exception: children is undefined`

Comment: fixed! replies[i] was just replies, sorry. seems to hang though, not sure why.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only for the 1st tweet, and it keeps running indefinitely: it causes "Warning: Irresponsive script" message and I have to press "Stop script"

Comment: It's because in the 2nd `for` the variable should be different than `i`, eg `j`.
I edited your answer and marked it as accepted. Thanks again.